# Correr un ciclo dentro de un array?

Tags: php, laravel

Como puedo hacer para agregar mas items dentro del array "items"?
tengo una tabla con varios items y quiero correr un foreach dentro para cargar cada uno de ellos, pero cuando lo hago me tira un error(syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' ) .
El proyecto esta hecho en Laravel 5.5

```
$preferenceData = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "id" => "Code",
            "title" => "Title of what you are paying for",
            "currency_id" => "ARS",
            "picture_url" =>"img/logomp3.gif",
            "description" => "Description",
            "category_id" => "Category",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "unit_price" => 1.0
        ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mas que es lo que quieres, no estoy seguro de haber entendido bien lo que buscas. pon un ejemplo de lo que estas intentando.

Comment: ¿En dónde es que estás buscando agregar elementos? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: estoy buscando realizar un pago con mercadopago, necesito la informacion de cada item que esta en el carrito, y el formato que permite mercadopago es ese.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes iniciar la variable como un array, luego solo tienes que añadir elementos de esta manera:

```
<?php
$preferenceData = array(
    "items" => array()
);

foreach (`condición aquí`) {
    $preferenceData['items'][] = array(`tu array aquí`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías meter los items que tienes en tu tabla en un arreglo  tipo

```
$tabe_items = array(
   [
    "id" => "Code",
    "title" => "some title"
    ...
   ],
   [
    "id" => "Code",
    "title" => "some title"
    ...
   ],
 );
```

y al ultimo unirlos a tu arreglo

```
array_push(preferenceData['items'],$table_items);
```